# Unable to parse xml with null content in azure logic apps

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am getting an XML with following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <datym>
     <bla bla>
   </datym>
   <datym>
     <bla bla>
   </datym>
</Data>
```

This i can successfully parsed to json and do all the work. Sometimes i am getting an empty xml with following format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data></data>
```

This however fail to parse as an xml or json using logic apps.So how do i do a validation if this is parsable XML or the empty XML? i thought of using contains() function after initiate a string but this is huge performance hit.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I thought your empty xml example is till parsable. I tried to parse a xml file to a json file. This is my xml content.

```
<Invoices
xmlns="http://gateway.com/schemas/Invoices"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://gateway..com/schemas/Invoices Invoices.xsd">
<DocumentInfo></DocumentInfo>
<Header></Header>
<Documents></Documents>
</Invoices>
```

After parse, this is the json content:

```
{
  "Invoices": {
    "@xmlns": "http://gateway.com/schemas/Invoices",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "@xsi:schemaLocation": 
    "http://gateway..com/schemas/InvoicesInvoices.xsd",
    "DocumentInfo": "",
    "Header": "",
    "Documents": ""
  }
}
```

So maybe you could refer to my Logic App flow. I used a xml file as a display.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: i actually used XPATH and it works. Thanks for your suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find a way around this. So  i thought i will answer my own so future others would find it useful.

My method is using XPATH.

Simply check the first node. If it returns empty array then its empty otherwise go with the normal processing.

```
xpath(xml(base64ToString(variables('content'))),'//datym')
```

or

```
xpath(xml(base64ToString(variables('content'))),'//datym[1]')
```